# Show/hide the scrollbar under specific circumstances through CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have an app that for the most part I do not want a displayed scrollbar, so I manually hide it with the following code:

```
// Chrome, Safari and Opera
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none; // IE and Edge
    scrollbar-width: none; // Firefox
}
```

However there will be one circumstace in which I will need to display a scrollbar, but I can't get it to be shown under those circumstances, say a particular class called `.show-scrollbar`.

I've been trying something like this:

```
.show-scrollbar {
   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
     display: initial;
   }
    -ms-overflow-style: initial; // IE and Edge
    scrollbar-width: initial; // Firefox
}
```

Unfortunately to no avail. Here is a demo of what my work looks like:

```js
const App = () => {

  return (
  <div>
    <div className='some-div'>
      <h3>Must NOT Show Scrollbar</h3>
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div className='some-div show-scrollbar'>
      <h3>Must Show Scrollbar</h3>
      At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;

    font-size: 16px !important;
}

.some-div {
 max-height: 100px;
 overflow: scroll;
 border: 1px red solid;
}

.show-scrollbar {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: initial;
  }
  
  -ms-overflow-style: initial;
    scrollbar-width: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

So anyway, how could I add it only for the elements that have the `.show-scrollbar` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is seems like a bug in `::-webkit-scrollbar`. Check out: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=152226

What you can do is search for the default scrollbar values and create a custom scrollbar, like so:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-height: 100px;
  border: 1px red solid;
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

.wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  all: unset;
  /* or display: none; */
}

.has-scrollbar {
  -ms-overflow-style: initial;
  scrollbar-width: initial;
}

.has-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  all: initial;
  /* or display: initial; */
}

.has-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.has-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Must NOT Show Scrollbar</h3>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
    accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab
    illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt
    explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut
    odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione
    voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum
    quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam
    eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat
    voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam
    corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?
    Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse
    quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo
    voluptas nulla pariatur?
  </div>
  <br />
  <div class="wrapper has-scrollbar">
    <h3>Must Show Scrollbar</h3>
    At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui
    blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores
    et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident,
    similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est
    laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita
    distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio
    cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus,
    omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem
    quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet
    ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque
    earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis
    voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus
    asperiores repellat.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you removed the 'display: none' and just tried overflow?

```
 .show-scrollbar {
overflow: auto;
}
```

or

```
 .show-scrollbar {
overflow: scroll;
}

or a combinator?

/*   former_element ~ target_element       */

.div-with-no-scroll ~ .div-immediately-following-with-scroll {
overflow: scroll;
}

you would need to remove your <br> between the div's for combinator
```

Comment: does the height of the content inside the divs change? that would affect the default behavior of scroll bars

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, the scrollbar should not appear on narrow screens.

```css
@media (max-width: NNNpx) {
   // Chrome, Safari and Opera
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
  body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none; // IE and Edge
    scrollbar-width: none; // Firefox
  }
}
```

and could appear on wider screens

```
@media (min-width: NNNpx) {
  //see the JosBroers answer
}
```

Comment: Suppose I botched my description and made it confusing. It isn't that I want it to show it on larger screens always, it is just under certain circumstances. So, when I have that class. However, on smaller screens it will never show. Anyway, now re-reading the post it wasn't worded appropriately and made it confusing. The main thing to focus here is to show when there is the `.show-scrollbar` class and hide otherwise.